# J'étais fâchée quand / alors que j'écrivais ces lignes

Tags: imparfait

Bonjour,

> J'**étais** fâchée quand j'**écrivais** ces lignes.

Est-ce que l'emploi de l'imparfait est correct dans les deux parties de la phrase ? Ou il serait préférable de remplacer "quand" par "alors" ?

Comment: @Archemar Merci. Je ne comprends pas " une interruption à venir".

Answer (score 4):

L'imparfait et le passé composé sont possibles :

> J'étais fâchée quand j'écrivais ces lignes.

> J'étais fâchée quand j'ai écrit ces lignes.

voire aussi le passé simple:

> Je fus fâchée quand j'écrivis ces lignes.

Les conjonctions/adverbes utilisés changent le sens de la phrase :

***Quand*** : Au moment où j'écrivais ces lignes, j'étais fâchée. (simultanéité)

***Alors*** : C'est parce que j'étais fâchée que je me mettais à  écrire ces lignes. (cause à  effet)

***Alors que*** : Au moment où j'écrivais ces lignes, j'étais fâchée (simultanéité + opposition possible entre les deux)

Comment: Merci. _Alors : C'est parce que j'étais fâchée que je me mettais à écrire ces lignes. (cause à effet)_ --- Oui ? _J'étais fâchée **alors que** j'écrivais ces lignes_. (a) Je pense que (a) = plutôt à _J'étais fâchée **pendant que** j'écrivais ces lignes_, non ?

Comment: *Quand*,  *pendant que* indiquent la simultanéité.  *Alors que* peut y ajouter une opposition, *Alors*, *donc* indiquent une conséquence.

Comment: Mais pas dans ma phrase, à mon avis. _J'étais fâchée **alors** (=donc) j'ai écrit ces lignes._ Là, il s'agit d'une conséquence. Mais dans ma prase _alors **que**_ = _pendant que_.

Comment: C'est ce que j'ai écrit dans mon commentaire précédent: **alors que** indique une simultanéité, pas une conséquence. Cette dernière requiers **alors** ou **donc** seuls. Cependant **alors que** peut aussi ajouter une opposition (*j'étais fâchée bien que j'écrivais ces lignes*). On ne peut pas savoir s'il y a opposition ou pas dans ta phrase.

Comment: Un exemple où l'opposition est manifeste : *J'étais fâchée alors que tu étais contente*.

Comment: Oui, dans cet exemple oui, mais dans le mien, on voit le contexte, le sens est surtout "pendant que".

Comment: C'est vrai. C'est de beaucoup l'interprétation la plus plausible.

Comment: @Oreste *J'étais fachée alors que j'écrivais ces lignes* n'est pas une bonne utilisation de "alors que". C'est très rare que "alors que" est utilisée sans opposition, et c'est de façon littéraire dans certains cas comme "Alors qu'il était encore enfant". Ici, même si il n'y a pas d'opposition apparente, il y a quand même un contraste entre lorsqu'il était enfant et lorsqu'il est adulte. Dans ton cas, il n'y a aucun contraste ou opposition. Dans ton cas, le terme a utiliser est "pendant".

Comment: @Oreste Par contre, si tu inverses les termes, c'est possible. "J'écrivais ces lignes alors que j'étais encore faché". Il y a un contraste entre être faché ou non. Il faut noter que "encore" ou "toujours" est généralement utilisé dans ce cas-ci. L'emphase est mise sur le fait que tu es faché au lieu d'une situation neutre comme "pendant".

Comment: @Simon Merci. _C'est très rare que "alors que" est utilisée sans opposition_ --- _**Alors que** j'étais en route vers ma maison, A. m'a appelée_ Cette phrase serait-elle rare ou littéraire ? Je ne le pense pas, mais peut-être que je me trompe.

Comment: @Oreste J'aurais du préciser rare à l'oral, car la majorité vont utiliser "pendant" dans cette situation. Donc oui, je suis d'accord avec Larousse ici, cette phrase est littéraire :). (Je la verrais dans un livre, ou dite par un conteur qui veut mettre de l'emphase sur le fait qu'il était en route. Dans le dernier cas, je pourrais voir une suite "Quand tout à coup...")

Comment: @Simon D'accord, merci beaucoup.

Comment: passé compos**é** 1ère ligne

Comment: @Oreste merci !

Comment: _J'étais fâchée quand j'écrivais ces lignes._ --- Est-ce que cette phrase veut dire _Je suis fâchée à chaque fois que j'écris ces lignes_ ou _J'écris ces lignes une seule fois et alors, pendant que je les écris, je suis fâchée_ ?