# Comme lorsque / pendant que / alors qu'il observait mes amis

Tags: conjonctions, imparfait

> A. se tient droit, comme **lorsqu**'il observait mes amis qui
> vandalisaient les statues.

Après avoir lu ce [fil](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/46794/alors-que-quand), je pensais que *lorsque + imparfait* devrait suggérer la répétition :

> Lorsqu'il arrivait à la maison signifie chaque fois qu'il arrivait à
> la maison mais alors qu'il arrivait à la maison signifie au moment où
> il arrivait (cette fois là) à la maison.

Pourquoi est-ce que, dans ma phrase, *lorsque* décrit une situation unique ? Je pensais qu'il fallait employer *pendant que* ou *alors que* au lieu de *lorsque* si je parle d'une scène singulière, même si *alors que* et *comme* pourraient être synonymes.

Comment: "Lorsqu'il arrivait à la maison" signifie chaque fois qu'il arrivait à la maison"; non, ce n'est vrai.

Comment: @Oreste Tu as mis *alors que* dans le titre mais cette conjonction n'apparaît pas dans le corps de la question.

Comment: @jlliagre J'ai ajouté une phrase à ma question.

Answer (score 1):

Selon le TLFi les deux possibilités envisagées sont correctes.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lorsque)) (caractères gras dus à user LPH)
> **A.** − Emplois temp.
> **1.** [Marque la simultanéité temp. entre le procès de la prop. sub. et celui de la prop. princ. (l'espace de *lorsque* coïncide avec celui du procès sub.; c'est dans cet espace que vient s'inscrire le procès princ.)] À l'époque où, au moment où. Synon. usuel quand.
> **b) [L'alliance avec l'imp. ou le prés. (ou avec le passé composé ou le plus-que-parfait de l'accompli) produit un effet d'itér.]**
> ♦ Dans les Exercices de saint Ignace, lorsqu'est venu le moment de l'élection, le retraitant se demande : quelle décision vais-je prendre? (Bremond, Hist. sent. relig., t. 3, 1921, p. 74).
> ♦ Lorsqu'un des vôtres arrive au pouvoir, c'est signe de richesse, c'est signe que la France a son plein d'huile, d'amitié et de raison (Giraudoux, Bella,1926, p. 48)
> ♦ ... nous avions une conversation muette, en frappant au plancher; c'était le moyen qu'elle employait pour m'avertir, quand elle rentrait, ou quand elle sortait pour aller chez sa mère, ou **lorsqu'elle souhaitait** que je descendisse pour causer... Restif de La Bret., M. Nicolas,1796, p. 81.
> **c) [L'espace de lorsque peut cependant être suffisant pour inscrire en lui un imp. duratif]**
> ♦ Je me souviens que **lorsqu'elle était** enfant, on lui interdisait le moindre amusement (Chardonne, Épithal.,1921, p. 9).
> ♦ C'est d'elle seule que vous auriez raison d'être jalouse, m'a-t-il dit **lorsque nous ne nous tutoyions** pas encore (Gide, École femmes,1929, p. 1255).

Après avoir vérifié  que « itération » signifie « répétition » les parties « b » et « c » dans la défintion du dictionnaire montrent clairement que les deux valeurs sont propres à l'usage de « lorsque ».

Le contexte est le facteur déterminant dans la décision de quel valeur du temps il s'agit (itération, duratif).

> A se tient droit, comme lorsqu'il observait mes amis qui vandalisaient les statues.

*Dans ce contexte, la valeur est ambigüe à cause du manque de précisions. Dans le cas suivant il n'y a plus de doute.*

- A se tient droit, comme  tous les samedi soirs lorsqu'il observait mes amis qui vandalisaient les statues. (*itératif*)
- A se tient droit, comme  lorsqu'il observait mes amis qui vandalisaient les statues samedi dernier. (*duratif*)

> Lorsqu'il arrivait à la maison signifie chaque fois qu'il arrivait à la maison mais alors qu'il arrivait à la maison signifie au moment où il arrivait (cette fois là) à la maison.

Non, il n'est pas nécessairement vrai que « lorsque » implique un effet [*itératif*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_it%C3%A9ratif) dans ce cas ; l'effet duratif est possible. Répétons le, le contexte décide.

- Lorsqu'il arrivait à la maison en ce soir de septembre 1985, il n'y avait pas de brume et la pleine lune éclairait la cour d'une lumière suffisante pour marquer les ombres distinctement. (exemple de user LPH ; cet usage de l'imparfait pour communiquer un effet duratif au cours d'une seule occasion est cependant littéraire.)

---

*Addition due aux commentaires de user Oreste [**I** c'était le moyen qu'elle employait pour m'avertir, quand elle rentrait, ou quand elle sortait pour aller chez sa mère, ou lorsqu'elle souhaitait que je descendisse pour causer... Là, ce sont des imparfaits d'habitude. // Par contre, cet exemple, je ne le comprends pas vraiment. C'est d'elle seule que vous auriez raison d'être jalouse, m'a-t-il dit lorsque nous ne nous tutoyions pas encore. Peut-être qu'il est possible de remplacer « lorsque » par  « à l'époque où » et alors cette utilisation devient possible...? **II** Peut-être que c'est ainsi : si lorsque signifie  « à l'époque où », il est possible d'employer l'imparfait même s'il ne signifie pas « à chaque fois que », mais si « lorsque » = « au moment où », il est impossible d'employer l'imparfait. (?)]*

**I** Dans ce contexte de tutoiement il n'y a pratiquement aucun doute  que l'on a affaire à une période, celle qui précède le moment où le changement de « vous » à « tu » s'est fait, et non à une série de moments au cours desquels le tutoiement aurait été réadopté chaque fois (quelle que soit la raison de  ce recomencemment). Cette idée de période unique est renforcée par le reste du contexte : « C'est d'elle seule que vous auriez raison d'être jalouse » ; il serait bizarre de répéter cela avant que le tutoiement recommence chaque fois. Donc, dans ce contexte courant on expérience un imparfait duratif.
Il est néanmoins possible de voir un imparfait d'itération dans cette subordonnée si l'on ajuste le contexte, mais « encore » n'est peut-être pas compatible avec l'idée d'itération et dans tous les cas ne semble pas très effectif dans le but de le confirmer ; en conséquence un bon style demande à mon avis qu'un renforcement soit fait : « Nous nous somme revus trois ou quatre fois et au cours de ces entrevues nous avons commencé par nous vouvoyer ; **chaque fois** [renforcement] il semblait très gêné lorsque nous ne nous tutoyons pas encore  mais ne proposait pas que l'on arrête de se vouvoyer. ».

Oui, il est possible de remplacer « lorsque » par « à l'époque où » ou une autre locution de sens similaire et l'imparfait est duratif, mais cela n'a aucune conséquence pour le temps, qui reste l'imparfait [descriptif](https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/indicatif-imparfait.php).

- C'est d'elle seule que vous auriez raison d'être jalouse, m'a-t-il dit à l'époque où nous ne nous tutoyions pas encore.

**II** - « si *lorsque* signifie *à l'époque où*[…] »

« Lorsque » ne signifie « à l'époque où » ou bien « à chaque fois que » qu'en vertue du *contexte sémantique* en conjonction avec le *contexte grammatical*, ce dernier n'étant pas limité à l'usage de l'imparfait. Ce sont les précisions que l'on ajoute et le temps qui font la signification. Donc, si « lorsque » signifie « à l'époque où » il existe un contexte sémantico-grammatical qui indique cela et si l'imparfait fait partie de ce contexte, il est bien sûr qu'il ne peut pas être reconnu comme ayant une valeur itérative (à chaque fois que) ; il s'ensuit que la question qui mène à votre « même s'il ne signifie pas « à chaque fois » ne se pose pas.

- mais si *lorsque = au moment où *, il est impossible d'employer l'imparfait.

Je ne crois pas cela, et le TLFi donne au « c) » des cas courants ; comme j'essaie de le montrer avec mon dernier exemple, dans le style littéraire « lorsque » combiné à l'imparfait résulte en un sens de  « lorsque » qui est « au moment où » dans un contexte où plus habituellement on trouve un passé simple ou un passé composé.

Voici encore un exemple qui remonte à 1999.

- Les premiers laïcs: lorsque l'Église naissait au monde ([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Les_premiers_la%C3%AFcs/8jtxAAAACAAJ?hl=fr))

Comment: _c'était le moyen qu'elle employait pour m'avertir, quand elle rentrait, ou **quand** elle sortait pour aller chez sa mère, ou **lorsqu**'elle souhaitait que je descendisse pour causer..._ Là, ce sont des imparfaits d'habitude. // Par contre, cet exemple, je ne le comprends pas vraiment. _C'est d'elle seule que vous auriez raison d'être jalouse, m'a-t-il dit **lorsque nous ne nous tutoyions** pas encore._ Peut-être qu'il est possible de remplacer _lorsque_ par _à l'époque où_ et alors cette utilisation devient possible...?

Comment: Peut-être que c'est ainsi : si _lorsque_ signifie _à l'époque où_, il est possible d'employer l'imparfait même s'il ne signifie pas _à chaque fois que_, mais si _lorsque_ = _au moment où_, il est impossible d'employer l'imparfait. (?)

Comment: @Oreste Pour répondre plus précisément à vos commentaires j'ai fais une addition à ma question ; n'hésitez pas à  demander plus d'éclaircissements.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Je vais relire vos explications ce soir, et oui j'ai encore une question, mais j'aimerais tout relire avant.

Comment: _Le contexte est le facteur déterminant dans la décision de quel valeur du temps il s'agit (itération, duratif)._ --- En fait, c'est ce que je pensais moi aussi, mais quelqu'un m'a dit que la phrase dont la structure est semblable à la phrase _Lorsqu'il arrivait à la maison, il a trébuché_ est incorrecte si on parle d'un évènement unique, et jlliagre le dit aussi dans ce [fil](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/46794/alors-que-quand), donc je ne sais plus qu'en penser. Ils disent qu'il faut employer _alors que_ et non _lorsque_ dans ce dernier exemple.

Comment: Je veux dire que l'on m'a dit  _Lorsqu'il arrivait à la maison, il a trébuché._ signifie une répétition et que si je veux parler d'un évènement unique, je dois écrire _alors que_. C'est bizarre, ces explications différentes...

Comment: @Oreste À mon avis cette phrase est correcte et il n'y a nul besoin de remplacer « lorsque » par « alors que »,  la raison de cela étant que l'imparfait prend une valeur d'imparfait de narration, laquelle donne une notion de durée à des actions exprimées d'habitude avec le passé composé ou du passé simple. « Lorsqu'il arrivait à la maison …. » signifie « Lorsqu'il arriva/est arrivé …. » avec une nuance supplémentaire ( réponse de [Punky Zoé](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/fr-imparfait-de-narration-narratif-historique-imparfait-employ%C3%A9-au-lieu-du-pass%C3%A9-compos%C3%A9.770031/)).

Comment: Merci, à mon avis aussi, cette phrase devrait être correcte. Sauf que deux autres personnes + jlliagre m'ont dit que non, sans m'expliquer pourquoi. C'est leur langue maternelle... mais si on essaie de raisonner la phrase _Lorsqu'il arrivait à la maison, il a trébuché_ devrait être correcte. Voici ce que j'ai trouvé _**Lorsque j'habitais** à Paris, je travaillais dans le XIIe arrondissement et j'allais tous les jours au travail en bus._ [lien](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-77257.php). Bizarre...

Comment: Voici un autre exemple [francaisfacile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/forum/lire.php?num=7&msg=39526) : _**Lorsque j'arrivais** à la gare, la pluie commença à tomber._ (...) _l'emploi de l'imparfait pour la première partie de la phrase et du passé simple pour la deuxième partie est discutable_ (...) _ce qui est incorrect , c'est l'emploi de deux temps différents . Puisque les deux actions sont simultanées , elles doivent être cojuguées en même temps(imparfait/imparfait ou passé simple/ passé simple_ Mais je comprends toujours pas pourquoi...

Comment: Pourquoi alors la phrase _J'étais fâchée quand j'ai écrit ces lignes._ [lien](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/48668/j%c3%a9tais-f%c3%a2ch%c3%a9e-quand-alors-que-j%c3%a9crivais-ces-lignes?rq=1) est possible ? Ou la phrase _Nous avons cuisiné quand tu dormais_ [lien](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/49636/j%c3%a9tais-jai-%c3%a9t%c3%a9-javais-%c3%a9t%c3%a9-si-concentr%c3%a9e-sur-le-sujet-x-que-jai-oubli%c3%a9-de) ? Peut-être que quelqu'un viendra éclairer notre lanterne...

Comment: @Oreste Attention, ne pas confondre « Lorsque j'habitais à Paris, je travaillais … » (Français facile, *Action passée ou un état passé qui a duré*) et « Lorsque j'arrivais à la gare, la pluie … » ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imparfait_de_l%27indicatif_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Emploi_narratif), ) ; la valeur est différente : habiter → durée, arriver → ponctuel, mais effet de durée obtenu par le biais d'un temps qui marque la durée ; en passant, noter que cet imparfait n'est rien d'autre que l'imparfait historique (En l'an 1492 Christophe Colomb découvrait l'Amérique) ; (1/3)

Comment: @Oreste   la différence entre « habitais Paris » et « découvrait l'Amérique ».//Non il n 'existe pas de telle règle : [concordance](https://www.conjugaison.com/grammaire/concordance-indicatif.html) : « J’étais à l’entrée du musée quand je l’aperçu. ». Le pourquoi est simple : le passé simple rend l'action ponctuelle (si elle ne l'est pas déjà en vertu du verbe lui-même) et l'imparfait, qui ne délimite pas l'action en un point mais offre un aspect de durée (2/3)

Comment: @Oreste   sert à donner un contexte de base dans lequel le point, ou en d'autres mots l'action ponctuelle se situe (cela en vertu du fait que c'est une convention du français à laquelle les auteurs adhèrent. (3/3)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133847/discussion-between-oreste-and-lph).